# Changing to two different tick on two figures in one window

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figures

Basically I am trying to change the ticks on the y axis to be different but keep the same x axis ticks on both. I have looked online and through the textbook but was unable to get what I was looking for.
I am attempting to label the top figure's y-axis as (-1,0,1,2), the bottom figure as (-0.2,0,0.2,0.4,0.6) and for both figures with an x-axis of (0,0.5,1,1.5,2)

```
x = linspace(0,2)
y1 = sin(2*pi*x);
y2 = exp(-0.5*2*pi*x).*sin(2*pi*x);


figure
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x,y1,'rs')

subplot(2,1,2);
plot(x,y2,'k*')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. You need to change the `YTick` and `XTick` properties of the axes, as well as the `YLim` property for the top plot, since by default Matlab tries to fit the axis with the range of data you have.

```
clear
clc

x = linspace(0,2);
y1 = sin(2*pi*x);
y2 = exp(-0.5*2*pi*x).*sin(2*pi*x);

figure
subplot(2,1,1);
hPlot1 = plot(x,y1,'rs');

%// The important part.
set(gca,'YLim',[-1 2],'YTick',-1:1:2,'XTick',0:.5:2)

subplot(2,1,2);
hPlot2 = plot(x,y2,'k*');

set(gca,'YTick',[-0.2,0,0.2,0.4,0.6],'XTick',0:.5:2)
```

Which looks like this:

[image]